# HTTP Header Bad Response Code: 404. Blog Content is Fine. Articles Generate 404s

Tags: facebook, http, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I'm having an issue where the HTTP headers aren't being seen in my article content nodes. In my blog content nodes, they are being seen.

Facebook linter gives me a 404 Bad Response.

Here's an article link that doesn't work:
http://thesalinepost.com/article/saline-city-council-discuss-12-hour-days-spd-funding-safd-real-estate-services-contract

Here's a blog link that does work:
http://thesalinepost.com/blog/editors-notes/upcoming-classes-and-activities-saline-community-education

Any idea what is causing this? I'm losing clicks because my facebook links have no picture, title or summary.

Answer (score 0):

> Facebook linter gives me a 404 Bad Response.

Your server is the one responding with this HTTP status code.

And using a service like f.e. this one: http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://thesalinepost.com/article/saline-city-council-discuss-12-hour-days-spd-funding-safd-real-estate-services-contract also shows a 404 answer, so this is a problem with your site/your CMS’ configuration, so start looking there.

Comment: Thanks. Where should I start looking? I've compared the headers of the blog content and article content and they seem the same to me. I don't understand why one is a good header and the other is not.